# Case statement code runs in Mars simulator but errors in QtSpim

Tags: assembly, mips

so as the title mentions I have written this code in the Mars MIPS simulator and assembling and running the code there works fine, no errors. When I take the same file to QtSpim and run it there I get the following error:

> ```
> Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400014
> [0x00400014] 0x0c000000  jal 0x00000000 [main]           ; 188: jal main
> ```

Seems that QtSpim has issues with me calling the label address of `CASE` and I'm not experienced enough to see why. Here is my code:

```
.data
jumptable: .word isD, is1, is2, is3, is4
currentvalue: .asciiz "Returned : i = "     #Used for result output
space: .asciiz " \n"                        #Used for result output

.text
MAIN:
li $a0, 0               #testing use of the argument register toholdinput
jal CASE                #set $ra and go to the case procedure

li $v0, 4               #load syscall 4 to print text
la $a0, currentvalue    #load the string value of currentvalue into $a0
syscall                 #print out currentvalue

li $v0, 1               #load syscall 1 to print integer
move $a0, $t3           #move the contents of $t3 to $a0
syscall                 #print the integer in $a0

li $v0, 10              #load syscall 10 to exit program
syscall                 #exit program


CASE:
    la $t3, ($a0)       #load 'i' into a temporary value since we will be using $a0 for syscalls shortly

    blt $a0, 1, isD     #jump to default if i less than 1
    bgt $a0, 4, isD     #jump to default if i greater than 4

    sll $t0, $a0, 2     #multiplies 'i' by 2^2
    la $t1, jumptable   #load the base address of the jump table into $t1
    add $t1, $t1, $t0   #$t1 = $t1(base address of table) + $t0('i' * 4)
    lw $t2, ($t1)       #$t2 is loaded with the address of label found in $t1
    jr $t2

    is1:
        addi $t3, $t3, 1    #increment 'i' by 1
        jr $ra              #jump back to the return address in main
    is2:
        addi $t3, $t3, 2    #increment 'i' by 2
        jr $ra              #jump back to the return address in main
    is3:
        addi $t3, $t3, 3    #increment 'i' by 3
        jr $ra              #jump back to the return address in main
    is4:
        addi $t3, $t3, 4    #increment 'i' by 4
        jr $ra              #jump back to the return address in main
    isD:
        li $t0, 0           #set 'i' to 0
        jr $ra              #jump back to the return address in main
```

Comment: I suspect SPIM is case-sensitive and tries jumping to `main`, while your code only defines `MAIN`.

Comment: Wow, spot on, I changed both Main and CASE to main and case respectively and voila I get my output. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've figured it out. (*Caveat:* I only have mars)

In your error message, the error came from line 188, so that's *not* part of your program. It's part of `spim` call code for `main`.

To define the `main` function, it *must* be [lowercase] *and* global:

```
.globl main
main:
```

Neither `mars` nor `spim` recognized your `MAIN:` as above. If `mars` can't find a main, it will start the program at the lowest address in the `.text` section. `spim`, however, just complains.

---

**UPDATE:**

> On another note, if you have a chance, I'm learning MIPS now, going by my comments, does everything seem on the up and up in my code?

I did my version of a code review, which means I annotated the source and cleaned things up until I understood what was going on.  In your case, this was just editing some comments. I did find a small [one line] bug in this process, which I fixed in the annotated code below.

You did a great job of commenting for the stage you're at. Some OPs post asm without any comments. Good comments [in any language] should show *intent*. That is, what you intend your program to do at a given point (the "what/why"). The actual asm instructions are the "how".

As you did, I recommend sidebar comments on most asm instructions. I also recommend a comment block above the function.

I cleaned up your comments as I would do for myself as some of them were like:

```
x = 23;  // set the value of x to twenty three
```

When you're learning asm, sometimes you have to do that to remember what the given asm instruction does. But, they can impede following the flow/logic of your program. So, I annotated those as "LEARNER" below [which, eventually, you would have deleted or shortened yourself] and replaced the sidebars with what I might do/suggest.

Also, it's perfectly okay to assume that an asm programmer is familiar with at least one high level language, so you can use comments with `i < 1` or `i += 3`, etc.

To speed up testing, I also added a user prompt for the argument to `case`.

Anyway, here's the annotated source [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
jumptable:  .word       isD,is1,is2,is3,is4
prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter case input argument: "
currentvalue:   .asciiz "Returned : i = "   # Used for result output
space:      .asciiz     " \n"           # Used for result output

    .text
    .globl  main

main:
    # prompt user for test value
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    la      $a0,prompt
    syscall

    # get user test value from stdin
    li      $v0,5                   # syscall: read integer
    syscall
    move    $a0,$v0                 # move to argument for case

    # LEARNER: testing use of the arg reg to hold input
    ###li       $a0,0               # test value for case function

    # LEARNER: set $ra and go to the case procedure (i.e. we are calling the
    # case function)
    jal     case                    # calculate [whatever case calculates ;-)]

    # print the prefix string
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    # LEARNER: address of currentvalue into $a0
    la      $a0,currentvalue
    syscall

    # print the value the 'case' function returned
    li      $v0,1                   # syscall: print integer
    # LEARNER: move the contents of $t3 to $a0
    move    $a0,$t3                 # get value to reg for syscall
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                  # syscall: exit program
    syscall

# case -- does what?
#
# RETURNS: what does it return?
#   t3 -- return value
#   FIXME: to follow ABI, this should be v0 but okay for small internal
#   functions like this one.
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- contains 'i' (FIXME: what is 'i'?)
#
# internal register usage (i.e. what registers get clobbered):
#   t0 -- offset into jump table
#   t1 -- address of jump table
#   t2 -- internal jump address
case:
    move    $t3,$a0                 # save 'i' to our work/return register

    blt     $a0,1,isD               # jump to default if i < 1
    bgt     $a0,4,isD               # jump to default if i > 4

    # LEARNER: multiply 'i' by 2^2 (4) --> i <<= 2
    sll     $t0,$a0,2               # get the offset into the jump table

    la      $t1,jumptable           # base address of the jump table

    # LEARNER: $t1 = $t1(base address of table) + $t0('i' * 4)
    add     $t1,$t1,$t0             # add offset to base address

    # LEARNER: $t2 is loaded with the address of label found in $t1
    lw      $t2,($t1)               # jump_address = jumptable[i]
    jr      $t2                     # jump to desired label

is1:
    addi    $t3,$t3,1               # i += 1
    jr      $ra                     # return to caller

is2:
    addi    $t3,$t3,2               # i += 2
    jr      $ra                     # return to caller

is3:
    addi    $t3,$t3,3               # i += 3
    jr      $ra                     # return to caller

is4:
    addi    $t3,$t3,4               # i += 4
    jr      $ra                     # return to caller

isD:
    # BUG: this should be t3
    ###li       $t0,0               # i = 0
    li      $t3,0                   # i = 0
    jr      $ra                     # return to caller
```

Comment: That makes sense, I just renamed the labels and it worked for me in Spim, haven't tried it in Mars as of the rename though.

Comment: On another note, if you have a chance, I'm learning MIPS now, going by my comments, does everything seem on the up and up in my code?

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I appreciate it, really!